# Can't post to mongo/express api

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, http, express

I'm trying to add to my mongodb database through my angular 2 frontend but It doesn't seem that the post is going through. I use morgan to log all requests and it shows nothing, then I don't see anything in my database.

my api route:

```
   // add venue
router.post('/add_venue', (req, res, next) => {
  let newVenue = new Venue({
    _id: req.body._id,
    name: req.body.name,
    street: req.body.street,
    city: req.body.city,
    state:req.body.state,
    zipcode:req.body.zipcode,
    busy:req.body.busy
  });

  Venue.addVenue(newVenue, (err, venue) => {
    if(err){
      res.json({success: false, msg:'Failed to add venue'});
    } else {
      res.json({success: true, msg:'User registered'});
    }
  });



});

router.get('/venue/:id', (req, res, next) =>{
    let venueID = req.params.id;
Venue.findById(venueID, (err, user) => {

    if(err) throw err;
    if(!venueID){
      return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Venue not found'});
    }
```

I haven't tried the get request yet. Here my model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const config = require('../config/database');

const VenueSchema = mongoose.Schema({
_id:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
name:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
street:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
city:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
state:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
zipcode:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
busy:{
    type:Boolean,
},




});


const Venue = module.exports = mongoose.model('Venues', VenueSchema);

module.exports.addVenue = function(newVenue, callback){
   newVenue.save(callback);
      }
```

and here's the service i'm using on the front-end. I'm getting no errors with angular 2, it's all just through the back-end.

```
    @Injectable()

  export class VenueService{
    constructor(private http:Http){
    }


    getVenue(id){
      var headers = new Headers();
      return this.http.get('//ec2 instance/venues/venues'+ id)
        .map(res => res.json());
    }
    addV
enue(newVenue){
      var headers = new Headers;
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      return this.http.post('(I'm using an ec2 address)/venues/venues', newVenue, {headers:headers})
        .map(res => res.json());
    }}
```

I'm using vscode, and I'm fairly new to javascript. Is there something I missed here?

Comment: instead of .map use .then and test it should work

Comment: .then didn't work. I ended up using .subscribe and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following way

**JS**

```
  var newVenue = {
    data: 'something'
  };

  $http.post('http://url/data', newVenue, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .then(res => console.log(res.data());
```

This way you can see what is coming response or test your rest apis/calls from **Postman** rest client app